# React navigation - React native - Strange header behavior

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Have strange behavior of header for StackNavigator. 
No any styles for header. What is `space` before title?

Using `react-navigation` library for routing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. That's lib issue.

For now resolved it like

`header: () => <View style={{ marginTop: isIphoneX() ? 44 : 0}} />`